# How yo add a custom button to select quality of the video in blogger post

Tags: php, html, blogger

I have a blog where I just post anime episodes.I post these videos in different qualities, so the problem is I have to add all quality videos at one post one after one. So I need a button which says select quality and after clicking it gives u a dropdown of different qualities and we could select it from that.
Note: I need this same for every post.

Comment: Refer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177445/bloggervideo-js-how-can-i-add-quality-levels-like-1080p-720p-480p