# blogger+video.js how can i add quality levels like 1080p, 720p, 480p

Tags: blogger, video.js

I add video.js in my https://www.blogger.com  website but how can I add quality levels like 1080p, 720p, 480p

Codes I added

In the head

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.16.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
```

In the body

```
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.16.0/video.js"></script>
```

In the post

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="480" poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B04gyvra-UorR0t5RGdmT3pPZ0k" type='video/mp4'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
        <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to utilize a plugin called [Video.js Resolution Switcher](https://github.com/kmoskwiak/videojs-resolution-switcher) and change the content in the post as shown in this example

```
<video id="video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls data-setup='{}' >
  <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4?sd" type='video/mp4' label='SD' res='480' />
  <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4?hd" type='video/mp4' label='HD' res='1080'/>
  <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4?phone" type='video/mp4' label='phone' res='144'/>
  <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4?4k" type='video/mp4' label='4k' res='2160'/>
</video>
```

Working example can be found at https://kmoskwiak.github.io/videojs-resolution-switcher/

Comment: as i said i use blogger so what i need to add and where (head,body,post))

Comment: p.s i dont know javascript yet thats why i need help

Comment: In the `<head>` tag , add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-resolution-switcher/0.4.2/videojs-resolution-switcher.min.css" />` , In the `<body>` tag, after the video.js script tag add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-resolution-switcher/0.4.2/videojs-resolution-switcher.min.js"></script>` . And in the post , add the snippet of code shown in the answer above (replace the src with the actual video you want to shown with the different resolutions)

Comment: so i need to have lets say 1 video in 3 different resolutions on google drive

Comment: Yes, you will have to create separate video files of respective resolutions and store them on google drive. Then only will the Video resolution switcher be truly useful.

Comment: thnx, one last question how fast does video.js load a video 1080p or 720

Comment: Video will load normally like it would have loaded in a `<video>` tag. There should be no perceived difference in the performance or load time of the video of the same resolution while using video.js. The only difference being that lower resolution video will load faster as compared to higher resolution ones thereby giving  your users a choice in circumstances where bandwidth is important (like while accessing your site via mobile internet)

Comment: do you know then any place where i can upload anime fansub videos without gb limit and add/play them with video.js

Comment: I apologize, but I don't have any information regarding that topic.

Comment: last question isnt there any way to upload just 1 720p video and change the qualitty

Comment: I don't have expertise in that area. I would suggest asking about it in http://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The plugin is no longer maintained: https://github.com/kmoskwiak/videojs-resolution-switcher/issues/133